# Oracle query returning differnet results for same set of data

Tags: oracle

I am facing a wierd problem where the same query is returning different results.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TX_HISTORY  WHERE acct = 7  AND ROWNUM
```

What is happening is that I know that for this account there are more than 100 records in tx_history. I want to get the first 100 records based on the processing date.
My data for this account is I have records from 2004 till 2011

The problem is sometimes it correctly shows the 100 records starting 2004 - but sometimes it shows me 100 records starting 2005

I read that this can be solved by:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from TX_HISTORY  WHERE acct = 7  ORDER BY acct,processing_date)
where rownum
```

so in my earlier query is it that the:
1> My understanding is that the order by is being applied after the rownum <= 100 and the results returned by oracle are in a random order on which row num is filtering

Though what is not understood why the results would vary 
Thanks,
~akila

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not specify any ordering (and in this case, as you already found out, you do not order the data being retrieved, you only sort afterwards), it is up to the database to return them in any order it sees fit.

It could for example just start reading the rows in the order they are stored, which changes as the data gets updated. It also does not have to start from the top of the table, it could start with the blocks already in the buffer cache.

Since you did not specify the order, the DB will choose (what it thinks to be) the least expensive way available to it at this particular moment.

Comment: Thilo - thank you and my apologies - I never did mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top(100) from ...........
```

its give top 100 rows which u want.

Comment: That part why the sorting does not work as expected is already answered. This question is why the result is not even consistent when you run the query repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

If you include `AND RowNum <= 100` Oracle will pull 100 records at free will. If you put it in

```
SELECT *
  FROM TX_HISTORY
 WHERE acct = 7
   AND ROWNUM <= 100
 ORDER BY acct,processing_date
```

it is performed on all records there are.

However, if you have

```
SELECT *
  FROM (select *
          from TX_HISTORY
         WHERE acct = 7
         ORDER BY acct,processing_date)
 where rownum <= 100
```

it is performed on the records returned in the sub-select (the `SELECT` within the `( )`. In other words Oracle uses a different set of records to perform `AND RowNum <= 100` on.

The ordering is performed on the records returned by the query, so it happens after the `WHERE`-clause. So you will probably still get varying results.

I hope I could make it clearer.

Comment: That part why the sorting does not work as expected is already answered. This question is why the result is not even consistent when you run the query repeatedly.

Comment: @Thilo: so you are complaining about one line of my answer?

Comment: I am just complaining that you did not answer the question at all, which was "why does the same query against the same data sometimes return a different result". The one line in your answer that even goes near is "The ordering is performed on the records returned by the query, so you will probably still get varying results". Why does that query return different records sometimes?